# How to set active sheet without loading an xlsx file?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using `PHPExcel` to generate an xl using php. I am not loading an xl sheet but creating new sheets using

```
$phpExcel = new PHPExcel();
$phpExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("My Sheet");
```

I want to set active sheet using phpExcel using `$phpExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName("2");`

but im getting an error `setActiveSheetIndexByName not defined function.`

Please help

Comment: Is it really that hard to type "excel" instead of "xl"?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You do, of course, need to create/add additional worksheets to be able to change the active sheet: using new PHPExcel() will only create a workbook containing a single sheet.

You can set the active sheet using either the sheet index (sheets are indexed from 0);

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
```

or by name

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('My Second Sheet');
```

Adding a new sheet using either the createSheet() or addSheet() methods will automatically set that new worksheet to the active worksheet. By default, any new worksheet will be given a name comprising the word "Worksheet" and a number until you use setTitle() to change it.

Comment: ya i added 3 sheets using addSheet()but i want to set the 1st sheet to active .. is it possible?

Comment: Of course it's possible: indexed from 0, the first sheet will be indexed at 0, so `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);`

Comment: Alternatively, `$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName($objPHPExcel->getSheetNames()[0]);` if you're running a version of PHP that allows array dereferencing

Comment: ya i  tried $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); but still getting the error.. function nt defined :(

Comment: If you're getting function not defined, then there's something severely wrong with the installation, I'm surprised you can even instantiate a PHPExcel object... I can't understand how it's possible to create the object without PHP also providing access to all the public methods of that object. It suggests that PHP itself is snafu

Comment: If PHP can't find a method for an object, then you should be getting an error message like: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::setActiveSheetIndexByName() in /myscriptFilename.php on line xx` What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: ya mark im getting this error only: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::setActiveSheetIndexByName() in my filename line no

Comment: I'M out of ideas.... I can't understand how an object can be instantiated, but PHP doesn't recognise the existence of its public methods... it goes against every rule of PHP coding, so I'm completely at a loss: look at the PHPExcel class file yourself for the setActiveSheetIndexByName() method, and see what I mean: Unless your version of the code has been edited and that method removed, it should be there, it should be public, it shouldn't give that error

Answer (score 4):

Add below function into Excel.php class file:

```
function setActiveSheet($sheetnumber) {
        $this->objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($sheetnumber);
    }
```

then call that function like this :

```
$phpExcel->setActiveSheet(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `ByName`. Try just `setActiveSheetIndex(2);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are directly manipulating the xml in workbook.xml

```
$replace = '#activeTab="\d"#i';
$with = 'activeTab="0"';
$newxmlfile=preg_replace($replace,$with,$newxmlfile); // force activetab to sheet 1
```