# PHPExcel Print current page in a cell

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel and I have the next issue:

In the template I'm using, I must print the current page and total pages in some cells and this goes in a custom header that are IN the rows and not the header  itself because the complex of the template.

I know, I can print those values in the header and footer but, is it possible to print the current page or total pages in a cell with PHPExcel?

Comment: "Pages"? Do you mean the worksheets/tabs at the bottom?

Comment: more like the pages that would print the excel

Comment: Ok, so we're not talking about worksheets here, but your data with some pagination that you've defined? Wouldn't printing the page number in a cell be like printing any other data, then? (Which I assume you know how to do :))

Comment: Explain how you would work it out in MS Excel itself, and then perhaps we can figure out if/how you can do it using PHPExcel

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say 'pages' you mean worksheets.

To get the amount of worksheets in PHPExcel try the following snippet:

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheetCount()
```

To get the name/index of your current sheet, you just need to keep track of your navigation between sheets, since switching between them is done by index, or by name, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18272456/6338083).

---

If it help you can get the current sheet's name using

```
$sheetName = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getTitle();
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4792687/6338083), and according to [this](http://www.osakac.ac.jp/labs/koeda/tmp/phpexcel/Documentation/API/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.html#methodgetActiveSheetIndex) documentation you can get the active sheet's index using

```
$sheetIndex = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheetIndex();
```

Good luck!